# How does Garbage Collection treat objects that go out of scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

I'm pretty new to c#, so i apologise if the answer to my question is painfully obvious...

I'm wondering if there is a difference between the way garbage collection treats the following two `Image` object references:

```
Size imgSize = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload01.FileContent).PhysicalDimension.ToSize();
```

, and

```
Size imgSize;
using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload01.FileContent))
{
    imgSize = img.PhysicalDimension.ToSize();
}
```

so in the first example, there is no stored image reference, and in the second, the `using` clause should force disposal.

Will there be any difference as to when GC will be able to clean up these two images?

Thanks in advance...

[EDIT:] To be clear, since this was flagged as duplicate, my question is how GC treats the image object in the first example, since after that statement has executed, i can no longer access the image object. (i think this is different from a general discussion on GC's treatment of `IDisposable` implementations).

Comment: From references point of view shouldn't be a difference, but if `img` actually requires to be disposed, then in first approach object will not be disposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is relation between GC, Finalize() and Dispose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344240/what-is-relation-between-gc-finalize-and-dispose)

Comment: Your first example is terrible, and you have a big un-manged GDI resource open that is never closed or disposed by you, if you called this method a lot, you will get a GDI out of memory error, not to mention other problems

Comment: At this stage in your learning, don't worry about how the GC works as it works well. Worry about using your the `using` statement where ever you can, disposing everything at the first possible time your can, and not putting everything on the one line

Comment: `there is no stored image reference,` The GC doesn't care whether there is a stored image reference or not - it cares whether or not the object is reachable (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2003/04/19/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/). In practical terms, whether or not there is an explicit `img` variable won't make a difference in terms of reachability for a Release build (it will in Debug build, but that is a side issue).

Comment: thanks @mjwills, i think that answers my question. So the Image in example 1 is not disposed even though it is no longer accessible in my code.

Comment: Correct. `IDisposable.Dispose` will usually be called in one of two ways. Using `using` or calling it directly. Now, a finaliser may, much later, try and do some cleanup (which is roughly equivalent to the cleanup done by `IDisposable.Dispose`) - but it is not deterministic. So you should (almost) always use `using`.

Comment: `my question is how GC treats the image object in the first example` If using a Release build, the GC treats them basically the same way, since they both become unreachable at roughly the same point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to dispose Image/Bitmap and PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808753/right-way-to-dispose-image-bitmap-and-picturebox).  ALSO: To repeat what everyone else has said: There's a *BIG* difference between the 1st example and the second (where "using" promptly closes the resource).  As a general rule of thumb, you should *ALWAYS* explicitly close (or use "using") with *ANY* resource (like a file, a database connection... or a disposable GC object).